# The transfer to the new environment of the old MVC applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with the transfer of the old MVC applications to the new environment. I do not have much experience with MVC. After updating all the possible libraries

main web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

<configSections>



<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />





<appSettings>

<add key="webpagesersion" value="3.0.0.0" />

<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />

<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />

<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />

<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

<add key="AdminEmail" value="admin@xxxxx.pl" />

</appSettings>

<system.web>

<sessionState timeout="10" />

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">

<assemblies>

<add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

<add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, 31BF3856AD364E35=PublicKeyToken" />

<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

</assemblies>

<runtime>

<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

<dependentAssembly>

<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />

<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />

</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>

<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />

<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />

</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>

<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />

<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />

</dependentAssembly>

</assemblyBinding>

</runtime>
```

during compilation to start in _Layout.schtml

```
@ {

AdEfektWeb.Models.Rows.Row_users loggedUser = AdEfektWeb.Models.Logic.Auth.getUser (User.Identity.Name);

}
```

throws an error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version = 4.1.0.0,
>   Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. Located definition manifesto set does not match the
>   assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I do not know why odwołusie the seating version 4.1.0.0 if it is a reference to versji 6.0.0. and a runtime version = v4.0.30319

With the festivities thanks for your help.

Comment: Try reinstalling `EntityFramework` using Nuget Package manager

Comment: Have you tried adding a runtime binding redirect into your web.config?  Some package might have a dependency onto EF 4.1 and you have installed v6.0 and therefore the redirect might be necessary.  If you installed your nuget packages from scratch this should get automatically fixed as it adds a runtime redirect.

Comment: The easiest way to 'upgrade' project is to create a new mvc project using the provided template, and then copy over all your old mvc codes and views into the new project. That way you can be sure all basic/common packages and references are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Nuget Console to update the packages by running the command:

```
Update-Package
```

> The Update-Package command without any parameters will update every 
>   package. You can update packages individually by using the ID
>   argument. For  more information about the update command, run get-help
>   update-package.

Updating the MVC project is somewhat tricky, I suggest using a guide, this is a good place to check if you are not forgetting something - [http://www.asp.net/](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

When updating MVC 3 to MVC 4 you can use the following link - [Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806)

If you are updating MVC3 to MVC5 - one way is to first upgrade to MVC 4 and then to MVC 5.

But as the link above suggests:

> The simplest way to upgrade is to create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project
>   and copy all the views, controllers, code, and content files from the
>   existing MVC 3 project to the new project and then to update the
>   assembly references in the new project to match any non-MVC template
>   included assembiles you are using. If you have made changes to the
>   Web.config file in the MVC 3 project, you must also merge those
>   changes into the Web.config file in the MVC 4 project.

This is also valid for MVC 5.

Comment: Upgrade from MVC 3 to MVC 5?